# How do I retrieve both .msg and .MSG files using Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, outlook

The following Python code retrieves only '.msg' files

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.msg' in f]
```

How do I add it so it will retrieve '.MSG' files as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.msg' in f or '.MSG' in f]
```

You can chain conditions in list comprehension with `or` and `and`